# C++ 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero

Tags: divide-by-zero

This code is working perfectly until 100000 but if you input 1000000 it is starting to give the error `C++ 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero`. I am sure it is something about floating points. I tried all the combinations of (/fp:precise), (/fp:strict), (/fp:except) and (/fp:except-) but had no positive result.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "iostream"
#define unlikely(x)(x)

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    begin:
    int k;
    cout<<"Please enter the nth prime you want: ";
    cin>>k;
    int cloc=clock();
    int*p;p=new int [k];
    int i,j,v,n=0;
    for(p[0]=2,i=3;n<k-1;i+=2)
    for(j=1;unlikely((v=p[j],pow(v,2)>i))?!(p[++n]=i):(i%v);++j);
    cout <<"The "<<k<<"th prime is "<<p[n]<<"\nIt took me "<<clock()-cloc<<" milliseconds to find your prime.\n";
    goto begin;
}
```

Comment: Seriously?!!! Can you please format your code so it's at least readable?

Comment: A division by 0 would result in infinitive results. i.e, you cannot divide a number with 0. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero)

Comment: Sorry, That was how I keep it in the console. I hope it is clearer now. @Mylleranton The operation has got nothing to do with dividing something to zero.

Comment: @Flashbond Couldn´t read the code, and I saw the tag "division-by-zero" so I just wrote my comment. Sorry.

Comment: For about the billionth time, use a debugger.  If you cannot debug, you cannot develop software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code displayed in the question does not initialize `p[1]` or assign a value to it. In the `for` loop that sets `j=1`, `p[j]` is used in an assignment to `v`. The results in an unknown value for `v`. Apparently, it happens to be zero, which causes a division by zero in the expression `i%v`.

As this code is undocumented, poorly structured, and unreadable, the proper solution is to discard it and start from scratch.

Floating point has no bearing on the problem, although the use of `pow(v, 2)` to calculate *v*<sup>2</sup> is a poor choice; `v*v` would serve better. However, some systems print the misleading message “Floating exception” when an integer division by zero occurs. In spite of the message, this is an error in an integer operation.

Comment: So, do you think it is normal that working until 100000 perfectly?

Comment: The most trivial debugging effort by the OP would have detected this.

Comment: @Flashbond: Yes. When you do not initialize memory, there is no guarantee about its contents. Your system may have to do different things to provide 100,000 elements than it does to provide 1,000,000 elements, and this may result in different data being left lying around after the work is done.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Is it a difficult thing to  initialize memory?

Comment: @Flashbond: You must assign a value to each object before you use the object. In particular, when you use `new` to create an array of `int`, you must assign a value to each element of the array before you use that element of the array. (You can use library routines, such as `memset`, to do this instead of writing your own code.) In some cases, people use `for` loop just after the `new` to assign a value (often zero) to each element in the array. In other cases, they write code carefully to assign values as they do other work.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Thanks a lot for the advice! It improved my vision. I did predefine `p[j]` for `j=1` and solved the problem. At least it seems solved for some hundered million. Thanks a lot again.